# If certain keys are pressed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I am building a web application and I need to figure this out.

For this project I need to use the keyup function. This on it's own is not that difficult:

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) { //Up arrow key
    moveListUp();
} else if(e.keyCode == 38){ //Down arrow key
    moveListDown();         
} else{
    $('.searchBox').focus();
}
```

As you can see, if the arrow keys are pressed, it needs to execute a function. But when any other key is pressed, it executes the focus function on the searchBox.

I don't want every key except the left and right arrow key to trigger the focus function. I only want numeric and alphabetic keys to trigger that function.

How can I achieve this without having to define an if-statement for every single key?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer (unfortunately), but perhaps `(/[\da-z]/).match(String.fromCharCode()):` might work to test the character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check your key against a regex like that:

```
$(window).on('keydown', function(e){
    var key_char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),
        regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;

    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //Up arrow key
        moveListUp();
    } else if(e.keyCode == 38){ //Down arrow key
        moveListDown();         
    } else if( regex.test(key_char)){ // matches only alphanumeric keys
      $('.searchBox').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just the one I was looking for, a regex answer! This works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check that the key is alphanumeric before calling `focus()`, in which case you can check that the code is within one of the correct ranges.

```
else if ((e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122))
{
     $('.searchBox').focus();
}
```

That is `else if ((uppercaseLetter) || (Number) || (lowercaseLetter))`

Answer (score 0):

Use return false at last else condition:

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) { //Up arrow key
    moveListUp();
} else if(e.keyCode == 38){ //Down arrow key
    moveListDown();         
} else if(e.keyCode > 46 || e.keyCode < 91){
    $('.searchBox').focus();
} else{
   return false;
}
```